# Are blocks a OK way to model a theme?

Tags: theming, blocks

I am trying to build a new theme. Are blocks a OK way to model a theme? Some sites seem to recommend them, others say that they should be avoided.

Comment: The main content section is a block...I'd say yes, that's pretty much expected

Answer (score 2):

Blocks are an important part in Drupal, but you don't model a theme with them.
Blocks are implemented from modules, using [`hook_block_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [`hook_block_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) (together other hooks); what themes implement are regions where those blocks are rendered. A theme cannot decide not to implement regions, since there are some regions Drupal requires from themes.

Eventually, a theme can alter how a block is rendered, but themes are not modelled around blocks.

Comment: I agree. There is a trade-off: the more block-aware your theme the less versatile it becomes. Blocks should be used to populate themes.